# Firestore security rules: "PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions."

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My Firestore database has some users and some `foo`s. A user can claim a `foo` if no-one else has claimed it yet. They claim one by creating a document at `/fooOwners/{fooId}` that has a single field called `owner`, which is a reference to their own user document.

I think I've captured that in these security rules:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    // Users
    match /users/{userId} {
      // Omitted: the usual user rules.
    }

    // Foo ownership
    // Uniqueness of foo IDs is enforced by using them as document IDs.
    match /fooOwners/{fooId} {
      // Signed in users can claim a new foo.
      allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;

      // They can read ownership of their own foos, but they can't see who else owns which foos. We only list this using the Admin API from Cloud Functions.
      allow get: if resource.data.owner == /databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid);

      // They also can't change ownership directly, only by deleting and recreating.
      allow update: if false;

      // And they can only remove ownership of a foo they own themselves.
      allow delete: if resource.data.owner == /databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid);
    }
  }
}
```

However, when `get()`ing a document for the ownership, I get `PERMISSION_DENIED`:

```
2018-12-03 21:38:20.197 8111-8111/cc.biketracker.android E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: cc.biketracker.android, PID: 8111
    com.google.android.gms.tasks.RuntimeExecutionException: com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu.getResult(Unknown Source:15)
        at cc.biketracker.android.provisioning.ProvisioningActivity.lambda$onBonded$5(ProvisioningActivity.java:500)
        at cc.biketracker.android.provisioning.-$$Lambda$ProvisioningActivity$xeA3U7VpXb53FkiwAhKinRUnZbY.onComplete(Unknown Source:6)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzj.run(Unknown Source:4)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6680)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.
```

I do that like this:

```
        DocumentReference ownershipRef = FirebaseContext.getFooOwnerRef(selectedFooId);

        ownershipRef.get().addOnCompleteListener((task) -> {
            if (task.getResult() == null) {
                // This should never happen.
                Logg.e(TAG, "No foo ownership result.");
                return;
            }

            if (task.getResult().exists()) {
                // Check ownership is already ours.
            }
        }
```

I do NOT get this exception if I just open up the `/fooOwners/{fooId}` documents with read and write set to true.

What's wrong with my rules? They tested OK with the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have been fixed by the following change to the `get` rule:

```
allow get: if resource == null || resource.data.owner == /databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid);
```

I guess when I initially `get()` the document, before it exists, there is no `resource.data` and no `resource.data.owner`.